# TSQL order results where column contains all values from a list

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a Movies table with a Title column.

1. "The a"
2. "the b"
3. "the c"
4. "the something"

When I query that column with the input "the something" - I am returning all movies with a title containing EITHER "the" OR "something". This is what I want.

My current issue is that I am unable to order my results first by titles that contain all of the words supplied in the input. 
Since the word "the" is so vague, many titles match it, and the titles with "something" get buried in the results list.

In this example when I query for "the something" - "the something" should be ordered at the top. But since the query matches all columns containing both "the" and "something" I don't know how to achieve this.

I need Movies.Title to be ordered by columns that contain all values from SplitStringTable where possible. If that is possible.

How I achieve my query is by performing an JOIN on the table with the list of values supplied in the input:

```
SELECT * FROM Movies m 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM dbo.splitstring(@input, ' ')) SplitStringTable 
ON m.Title LIKE '%' + SplitStringTable .[Value] + '%'
```

Any thoughts on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Pardon me everyone, I explained my scenario all wrong. I am returning any record where Title contains ANY of the values from the SplitStringTable. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Not clear. Please provide representative sample data and the desired result.

Comment: I think this is very clear. But I will edit with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will return a row for each word matched; so you could group by the fields in the `Movies` record and then `ORDER BY count(*) DESC`.  Since I don't know all the fields I can show you only approximately what I mean:

```
SELECT m.TITLE
  FROM      Movies m 
       JOIN (SELECT * FROM dbo.splitstring(@input, ' ')) s 
         ON m.Title LIKE '%' + s.[Value] + '%'
 GROUP BY m.TITLE
 ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

But unless `TITLE` is unique this won't work right.  To make sure it orders the rows correctly, and to be able to see all the other fields, you need to include each field of the `Movies` table in the `GROUP BY` expression.

As an aside, there are probably better tools than SQL for this type of search, though perhaps you'll get results you find sufficient.  But one refinement I would suggest:

```
ON ' ' || m.Title || ' ' LIKE '% ' + s.[Value] + ' %'
```

may help avoid matching "the" against "theory", "another", etc.  If you can always rely on whole-word matches, that is...

Comment: I understand the need for the GROUP BY, but I don't see how this will ORDER BY my results by the values in the SplitStringTable?

Comment: The way you're explaining the order you want is very unclear, so I'm going by your one example: that you want titles that match all words to be first.  If you group by the `Movie` record, then the group `count(*)` will be the number of words that matched, so sorting on that (descending) puts the matches against all words first.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you for the explanation. :)